# Applying XSLT template based on conditions

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following template that I want to use on my xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="data/test/row> <!-- This 'match' is from database -->
   <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
       <input type="checkbox" id="someid" name="somename" value="{CATEGORY_ID}" /><xsl:value-of select="CATEGORY_NAME}"  />
    </label>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data/test/row> <!-- This 'match' is from database same as above -->
   <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
       <input type="checkbox" id="someid" name="somename" value="{CATEGORY_ID}" disabled="true" /><xsl:value-of select="CATEGORY_NAME}" />
    </label>
</xsl:template>
```

I am stuck in formatting the above 2 based on roles in my xslt.

How do I formulate in my xslt in such a way that the templates are read based on say, roles?
For example,

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="ROLE_NAME = 'Normal User'>
       <!-- use disabled input-->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- use enabled input-->
    </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose> 
<!-- Role comes form another place... Here is a sample: -->
<ROOT>
   <ROLE_NAME>Admin</ROLE_NAME>
   <ROLE_NAME>Normal User</ROLE_NAME>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Where does that information come from? Your source document? Is it a security role?

Comment: Yes, it can be considered a security role so to speak.

Comment: Is it available in your source document?

Comment: @helderdarocha, definitely, do assume that all the data as been already been up and available. I just need to find out the way to actually formulate this. :)

Comment: If it's not an information that's available in your source document, you can send it via a parameter through the program that runs the XSLT transformer. Then inside the XSLT you can read that parameter via a variable stored in a global `<xsl:param>`

Comment: Because if it's in your source XML, you can retrieve it somehow via XPath. And if it is not, you can send it as a parameter, and retrieve it via `<xsl:param name="role">` and then use `when="$role = 'admin'`

Comment: Is that located below the root of your input source XML? Or in another XML document?

Comment: I see. Those are the role names that you have, but where do you get the one that is currently running the processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to get the role information somewhere. If it's some data in your source XML, you can extract it via XPath. Since it's a runtime information (the role of the current user) it might be obtained through a parameter. I'll assume you have that role somehow and you attribute it to a parameter or variable.

To test it, you an attribute an initial value to the `$role-name` variable adding `select="`Normal User'"`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:param name="role-name"/>
...

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In some template matching a parent node, you can test the parameter, and decide which template you want to call using the `mode` attribute in `<xsl:template>`:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$role-name = 'Normal User'">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="disabled"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="enabled"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>
```

`enabled` and `disabled` are arbitrary names I chose for the modes. You now have to label the templates accordingly. They will now match not only the XPath expression, but also the `mode` name:

```
<xsl:template match="data/test/row" mode="enabled"> <!-- This 'match' is from database -->
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="someid" name="somename" value="{CATEGORY_ID}" />
        <xsl:value-of select="CATEGORY_NAME"  />
    </label>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/test/row" mode="disabled"> <!-- This 'match' is from database same as above -->
    <label class="checkbox-inline"> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="someid" name="somename" value="{CATEGORY_ID}" disabled="true" />
        <xsl:value-of select="CATEGORY_NAME" />
    </label>
</xsl:template>
```

If your current role information is in an external document, you can also assign it to a parameter or variable using the `document()` function (the path and the file name were chosen arbitrarily):

```
<xsl:param name="role-name" select="document('runtime-info.xml')/user/role"/>
```

And if it is somewhere in your source document, you just have to find it and discover how you can get that data via XPath.